# Is there any closed form solution available for following integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I want to solve following integral $$\int_{0}^{x}\int_0^{x}\cdots \int_0^{x}(Mx-x_1-x_2-\cdots x_M)\ln (Mx-x_1-x_2-\cdots x_M)e^{-x_1}\cdots e^{-x_M}dx_1\cdots dx_M$$ where $x$ and $M$ are positive constants. Any approximation or hint is also welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do the change of variables $x \to y$ with  $y_1 = \sum_i x -x_i$, and $y_j = x-x_j \quad \forall j \ne 1$.
The Jacobian of this change of variable is $1$, so the integral $\text{R}$ is equal to

$$
\text{R} = \frac{1}{\exp(Mx)}  \int_{x}^{0} \dots \int_{x}^0 \int_{x + \sum_{i=2}^n y_i}^{\sum_{i=2}^n y_i} y_1 \ln y_1 \exp (y_1) dy_1 dy_2 \dots dy_{M} 
$$
Then you integrate by parts (derive $y_1ln(y_1)$, integrate $exp(y_1)$), and you can have an expression with the exponential integral (special function) since you need to integrate $ln(y_1)exp(y_1)$ (integrating by parts gives you $exp(y_1)/y_1$).

Since you then need to integrate the exponential integral (special function) afterwards, there is no closed form for this integral in my opinion.

OLD ANSWER: **NOT RELEVANT**, only gives a upper bound on the integral.
Do the change of variables $x \to y$ with  $y_1 = \sum_i x -x_i$, and $y_j = x-x_j \quad \forall j \ne 1$.
The Jacobian of this change of variable is $1$, so the integral $\text{R}$ is smaller than (the integration domain is to big, compared to the right integral)
$$
\text{R} \le \frac{1}{\exp(Mx)}  \int_{x}^{0} \dots \int_{x}^0 dy_2 \dots dy_{M} \int_{ Mx}^{0} y_1 \ln y_1 \exp (y_1) dy_1
$$
$$
 = - \frac{(-x)^{M-1}}{\exp(Mx)} \int_{0}^{Mx} y_1 \ln y_1 \exp (y_1) dy_1
$$
Then you integrate by parts (derive $y_1ln(y_1)$, integrate $exp(y_1)$), and you can have an expression with the exponential integral (special function) since you need to integrate $ln(y_1)exp(y_1)$ (integrating by parts gives you $\exp(y)/y$).

Comment: thank you for your answer but i request you please add some steps

Comment: I think your definitions of $y_1$ and $y_j$ are quite confusing

Comment: I think although the substitution is correct however the limits are such that we can not convert it into a simple single integral the limits will actually make us to integrate all the integral one within the other.

Comment: What don't you understand about the definition of my $y_i$'s ? (I changed the integral to reflect the fact my integral is a real integral on $y_1$.)
I don't have only one integral. I added more steps to reflect this.

Comment: Now I understand the definitions of $y_i$'s but please check the limit of $y_1$ is not from $0\to Mx$ because of the dependence of $y_1$ on all other $y_i$'s. Hence the answer you wrote is, in my view, incorrect. I think the limit of $y_1$ will go from $y_2+y_3 \cdots y_M \to x+y_2+y_3 \cdots y_M$. Please tell me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: My integration domain is wrong. I'll try and correct this.

Comment: what do you think the limit of $y_1$ that I mentioned in my comment is correct? Thank you

Comment: I edited my answer. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But in my opinion the integral can be solved in closed form (may not be a very nice looking expression) and I am trying to  solve for $M=3$ case. I am using the strategy you mentioned (that is splitting by parts) and I think I am making progress in the right direction. I will share with you if I get the correct answer.

Comment: I believe that you will probably not have a closed form for $M=2$.
Keep me updated, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are right but I will share with you my solution for $M=2$ case. Do you know any numerical way through which the solution can be verified. Actually I do not know how to check my answer thats why I am asking you. Thank you

Comment: There is a very good "numerical integration" wikipedia page to understand how it works.
If you don't want to code it from scratch, you may find solutions in python, matlab, R, maple, ...

Comment: I have been able to the solve the integral for $M=2$ case and I think the procedure can be repeated for any value of $M$. Although the procedure is lengthy and cumbersome. The problem I faced was the evaluation of $Ei(0)$ which I avoided by using a trick and an identity from the Gradeshteyn book. If you have any problem in solving the above integral then I will be more than happy to help. But adding the solution whole solution might take a lot of time.

Comment: The only thing I wonder is how you got the integral of $Ei$ figured out, could you tell me ?

Comment: here is the link for integration of $Ei(ax)$ with WA. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+Ei(ax) further we can see that $xEi(x)$ goes to zero as $x$ goes to zero. I hope this helps.