# How to convert from multiple integrals to single integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I want to solve following integral $$\int_0^t\cdots \int_0^t (x_1+x_2\cdots x_M)dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_M$$ Is there some way through which I could convert these multiple integrals to single integral (for example through change of variable like $y=x_1+x_2\cdots x_M$). Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the integrand the sum of all $x_m$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes like $x_1+x_2+\cdots x_M$

Comment: @YvesDaoust i am sorry for directing you to another question but do you think the answer provided for following question is correct? (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241499/is-there-any-closed-form-solution-available-for-following-integral/2241551#2241551). I will be very thankful to you for your comment. Actually I am unable to understand the transformation of the variables into single variable

Comment: Why are you asking this? If your motivation is to simply learn how to do such integrals then it seems very strange to impose arbitrary rules (have to reduce it to one single integral whatever that means). You cannot reduce it to a one-dimensional integral with a substitution - the best case scenario is if the additional integrals become trivial as in the answer below. If your motivation is to understand the question you link to above then you would be better off asking about this directly.

Comment: @Winther you are right I am actually interested in that linked question. How did the integral converts to single integral in that question is what I am interested in knowing

Answer (score 3):

You can't reduce this down to a single integral, but you can switch variables so that the integrand depends on one variable only.  Here's how to do it:

We define new variables $y_i$ such that
\begin{align*}
y_1 &= x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_M \\
y_2 &= x_2 \\
y_3 &= x_3 \\
&\vdots \\
y_M &= x_M
\end{align*}
The inverse transformations are
\begin{align*}
x_1 &= y_1 - y_2 - y_3 - \dots - y_M \\
x_2 &= y_2 \\
 &\vdots \\
x_M &= y_M
\end{align*}
and so the Jacobian matrix is
$$
\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial y_i} =
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1 &  & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 &  & 0 \\
& \vdots & & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
The determinant of this matrix is then 1, and so we have
$$
\idotsint f(x_1 + \dots + x_M) dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_M = \idotsint f(y_1) \left| \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial y_i} \right| dy_1 dy_2 \cdots dy_M \\= \idotsint f(y_1) dy_1 dy_2 \cdots dy_M.
$$

At this point, if the limits of integration for $y_1$ are independent of all the other $y_i$'s, one could factor this out as
$$
\left[ \int f(y_1) dy_1 \right] \left[\idotsint  dy_2 \cdots dy_M \right]
$$
and now you only have one non-trivial integral to perform (since the multiple integral over $y_2$ through $y_M$ is the integral of a constant.)  Whether or not you can do this will depend on the precise form of your region of integration.

---

**EDIT:** Somehow I missed that you did in fact provide concrete limits of integration:  for all $x_i$, we have $0 \leq x_i \leq t$.  To translate these into limits on the $y_i$, we first note that obviously we must have $0 \leq y_i \leq t$ for $i \geq 2$, since in these cases $y_i = x_i$.  But the integral over $y_1$ is a little more subtle.  Since $y_1 = x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_M = x_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_M$, the range of allowable $y_1$ for a given $y_2, \dots, y_M$ is
$$
y_2 + \cdots + y_M \leq y_1 \leq t + y_2 + \cdots + y_M, 
$$
and so the integral in terms of the $y$ variables becomes
$$
\int_0^t \int_0^t \cdots \int_0^t \left[ \int_{y_2 + \cdots + y_M}^{t + y_2 + \cdots + y_m} f(y_1) dy_1 \right] dy_2 \cdots dy_M.
$$
Note that the limits of integration for $y_1$ are *not* independent of the other $y_i$.  This means that in general, the result of the $y_1$ integration will be a complicated function of $y_2$ through $y_M$, which you will then have to integrate with respect to all of the other variables.

You might be able to do a clever change of order of integration to make this more tractable, but I don't immediately see how.  For the specific case of $f(y_1) = y_1$, the technique proposed by @Med is probably better;  for a general $f(y_1)$, you might be stuck with doing $M$ integrals.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and detailed substitution method description. However, I have one confusion. I think the limit of $y_1$ is from $0$ to $Mt$ and if this limit is used then the answer does not matches with the answer of Med below. Where could be the problem? I hope to hear a response soon.

Comment: You mentioned that "whether I will be able to perform the integration will depend on the region of integration". With the limits that I mentioned in my OP I believe the limit of $y_1$ (the function for non-trivial integral) are from $0\to Mt$. Is it correct or not? Please correct me if I am wrong. Because I am unable to see any other thing wrong in your answer except the limits (of which I have confusion). Thank you.

Comment: @FrankMoses:  The limits of integration for $y_1$ are not actually from $0$ to $Mt$;  see my edited response for details.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^t\cdots \int_0^t (x_1+x_2\cdots x_M)dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_M=\sum_{i=1}^{M}\int_0^t\cdots \int_0^t (x_i)dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_M$

For each term in the summation, first take the integral with respect to $dx_i$ and then with respect to the rest of the variables.

$\sum_{i=1}^{M}\int_0^t\cdots \int_0^t (x_i)dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_M=M \times \frac{t^2}{2}\times t^{M-1}=\frac{Mt^{M+1}}{2}$

Let me know, if it is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I think your answer matches with that of @Michael Seifert if there is a square on $M$ also. Or do you think there is some problem with his approach. I hope to hear a response soon.

Comment: @FrankMoses, The approaches are different. But, the final result should be the same. I do not think $M$ should be squared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept applied in variation iteration method or variation of parameter method. This is done by multiplying the functional of the converted single integral with Lagrangian or Wronskian multiplier.

Let me know the outcome.

Comment: I guess this more a comment than a suggestion.

Comment: Yes, this is very possible. You can use the approach as displayed in pages 19 and 20 of the Text."Linear and Nonlinear Integral Equations: Methods and Applications" by Abdul-Mujid Wazwaz.