# where is the problem in following integration with substitution? A basic query

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I am interested in solving the following integration $$\int_0^t\int_0^{t}\cdots \int_0^{t}(x_1+x_2+\cdots x_M) dx_1 dx_2\cdots dx_M$$ Now if I use following substitution $$y_1=x_1+x_2\cdots x_M\\ y_2=x_2\\ \vdots \\y_M=x_M$$ then the Jacobian of this transformation will be $1$ and the limits of $y_1$ will go from $0\to Mt$, of $y_2$ from $0\to t$, and similarly of $y_M$ from $0\to t$. The integral after substitution will become $$\int_0^t\int_0^t \cdots \int_0^t \int_0^{Mt}y_1dy_1 dy_2 \cdots dy_M$$ $$\int_0^{Mt}y_1dy_1\int_0^{t}dy_2\cdots \int_0^{t}dy_M$$ $$\frac{(Mt)^2}{2}\times t^{M-1}$$ however this answer is different from what we get through simple integration without any substitution (the answer achieved through simple integration is $\frac{Mt^2}{2}\times t^{M-1}$). Is there something terribly wrong with what I am doing? I will be very thankful if somebody could help me in understanding the problem with this approach. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work more on the domain. For example, if $t=3$ and $M=2$ the domain $0<x_1<3$ and $0<x_2<3$ transforms into the domain $D$ satisfying the inequalities $0<y_1-y_2<3$ and $0<y_2<3$ which looks like this:

[image: parallellogram]

If we want to use this, then
$$
\iint_D y_1\,dy_1\,dy_2=\int_0^3\int_{y_2}^{y_2+3}y_1\,dy_1\,dy_2=\int_0^3\bigl[\frac{1}{2}(y_2+3)^2-y_2^2\bigr]\,dy_2=27.
$$

I leave it to you to handle the general case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Just to clarify my understanding I think the inner most limits (that of $y_1$) are dependent on the rest of $y$'s and all the other limits are from $0\to 3$. I have verified my this conclusion for $M=3$ and it works fine and I hope its right. BTW thank you so much for your identification of my problem.

Comment: Indeed, the innermost limits are the ones that were wrong. Good luck!

Comment: and unfortunately only those limits are preventing me to convert it into a simple integral. Actually this limit problem is also done by two other people who tried to answer similar question but only you provided the correct limits. Thank you. (the links to those question are as follows: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241499/is-there-any-closed-form-solution-available-for-following-integral/2241551#2241551, and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241772/how-to-convert-from-multiple-integrals-to-single-integral/2241881#2241881)